# Scroll to position (javascript)

Tags: scrollbar, javascript

I'm trying to get javascript to scroll the page to a target position, something like:

```
scrollbarxpos += (targetscrollbarxpos - scrollbarxpos) / 100.0f;
```

And basically keep calling that line of code until scrollbarxpos = targetscrollbarxpos.

Any idea how I can go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always use jQuery:

http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/vJmcK/

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at the [scrollTo](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.scrollTo) function? It allows you to scroll to a position on a page with x- or y- coordinates. If you want to animate the scroll, you could use some combination of `setInterval` and `clearInterval` to call `scrollTo` until you've reached your desire y-position.